# Error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified

Tags: mysql, bash, docker

I'm new to docker. I've been following this tutorial: https://medium.com/coderscorner/connecting-to-mysql-through-docker-997aa2c090cc . I've set up the root password but once I tried to access the mysql command, it throws out this database is uninitialized error. Also, when I do `docker-compose up` command to pull the needed modules, it gives out an **django.db.utils.InternalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'bitpal'")**. The command I placed was:

`docker run --name=mysql -e MYSQL_USER=root MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql`

I reckon I've searched for answers here but I couldn't be sure of what's wrong.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  # Redis
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    hostname: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DB=bitpal
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"


  # Redis
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    restart: always
    hostname: redis
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"


  # Django web server
  bitpal:
    image: python:3.5
    restart: always
    hostname: bitpal
    container_name: bitpal
    working_dir: /bitpal
    command: ./bin/start_dev.sh
    volumes:
      - ./bitpal:/bitpal
      - ./etc/config:/etc/config
      - ./log:/log
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - mysql
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      # Database
      - DB_NAME=bitpal
      - DB_USER=root
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
      - DB_HOST=mysql
      - DB_PORT=3306


  # Celery worker
  worker:
    image: python:3.5
    restart: always
    container_name: worker
    command: bash -c "./bin/install.sh && ./bin/celery_worker.sh"
    working_dir: /bitpal
    volumes:
      - ./bitpal:/bitpal
      - ./etc/config:/etc/config
      - ./log:/log
    links:
      - mysql
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis


  # Bitshares websocket listener
  websocket_listener:
    image: python:3.5
    restart: always
    container_name: websocket_listener
    command: bash -c "./bin/install.sh && ./bin/websocket_listener.sh"
    working_dir: /bitpal
    volumes:
      - ./bitpal:/bitpal
      - ./etc/config:/etc/config
      - ./log:/log
    links:
      - mysql
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis


  # Nginx
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.12.1
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./bitpal:/home/bitpal/bitpal/bitpal
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - bitpal
```

My directory looks like this.

```
`**ROOT**
     `root: .gitignore, docker-compose.yml, docker-compose-production.yml... 
     /bitpal /etc /log /nginx /public_html`

**ROOT/bitpal**
      `.gitignore, Dockerfile, Makefile, manage.py... /bin /bitpal /media 
      /static /tests`
```

All the project's `.sh` files are stored under root/bitpal/bin. Do I place `wait-for-it.sh` there instead or place it in bitpal and nginx folders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This tutorial you were following is incomplete. It didn't tell you that you must wait until the db is initialized if you want to use it.

Just after running the database container via `run` command, you should check the logs of this container and **wait until the DB initialization 
 process is complete**

You can do it with:

```
$ docker logs -f <container name>
```

Where `container name` in your case is `mysql`. When you see that db is initialized and DB is started, just detach (ctrl+c) from the logs and continue on.

Your DB is ready to use now.

**important note considering your compose file**

This compose file is not going to work because the other services like `bitpal`/`worker` are not waiting for the DB service to initialize.

Initially download a `wait-for-it.sh` script, that'd allow other servies to wait for your database when using compose file to setup your application. The script, made by vishnubob, is available [here](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh), then copy it to all the catalogs where your services requiring database are.

In the same catalogs create a `docker-entrypoint.sh` files and write them like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
sh -c './wait-for-it.sh mysql:3306 -t 30'
exec "$@"
```

Then, in your compose file add entries in every service that require DB (and where you places `wait-for-it.sh` script) that will execute the waiting script:

```
entrypoint: ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Then, your services will wait for the DB until it's initialized and ready to accept connections.

In the edits I'll add straight forward catalog tree so that you can more clearly see how these files should be placed.

This is one of the only efficient methods because `depends_on` is not waiting for the db service to be initialized as it's clearly stated in the official docs.

**edit with files location explanation**

```
root 
   - bitpal
      + *some service files*
      + wait-for-it.sh
      + docker-entrypoint.sh
   - some_service_requiring_db
      + *some service files*
      + wait-for-it.sh
      + docker-entrypoint.sh
   - docker-compose.yml
```

And your compose file should be like:

```
version: '2'
services:
  # MySQL service definition
  mysql:
    # like you have

  # some services

  # Django web server
  bitpal:
    # ...
    entrypoint: ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
    # further declarations
```

Comment: My directory looks like this.

**ROOT**
`root: .gitignore, docker-compose.yml, docker-compose-production.yml... /bitpal /etc /log /nginx /public_html`

**ROOT/bitpal**
`.gitignore, Dockerfile, Makefile, manage.py... /bin /bitpal /media /static /tests`

All the project's .sh files are stored under root/bitpal/bin. Do I place `wait-for-it.sh` there instead or place it in bitpal and nginx folders?

Comment: Update: the DB seems initialized, but now I still couldn't connect to it? It gives me an error of `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)")'.` When running `docker exec -ti bitpal mysql `without params, `caused exec file not found in $PATH": unknown` error