# Password authentication failed for Docker's postgres container

Tags: django, database, postgresql, docker

I am trying to dockerize my Django project. For this purpose, I am trying to divide the whole project into 2 parts

- The whole web related things in one container.
- Database i.e Postgres in another

I am creating the Postgres database container using command:

```
docker run --name postgres -it -e POSTGRES_USER=username -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword postgres
```

When this postgres instance started running I entered the shell postgres instance using:

```
docker exec -it postgres /bin/bash
root@ae052fbce400:/# psql -U psql
```

Inside Psql shell that i got, I am creating the Database named `DBNAME` and granted all the privileges to `username`;

Database settings inside the webapp container is:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'DBNAME',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'mysecretpassword',
        'HOST': 'postgres',
        'PORT': 5432
    }
}
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
services:
    web:
        image: 1ce04167758d  #image build of webapp container
        command: python manage.py runserver
        volumes:
            - .:/code
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        depends_on:
            - postgres
    postgres:
        image: postgres
        env_file:
            - .env
        expose:
            - "5432"
```

When I ran `docker-compose up` I am getting the following error:-

```
web_1       | django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "username"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you created two database services. One manually via `docker run` and one via `docker-compose`. Unfortunately both unusable, meaning they'd have to be reconfigured in order to cooperate.

**Scenario 1 - using a separate DB**

You should remove the database definition from compose file - so that it looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
    web:
        image: 1ce04167758d
        command: python manage.py runserver
        volumes:
            - .:/code
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
```

And in your config you should change `postgres` to your host machine - for example `192.168.1.2`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'itoucan',
        'USER': 'mannu',
        'PASSWORD': 'mysecretpassword',
        'HOST': '192.168.1.2',
        'PORT': 5432
    }
}
```

Then, run a separate database service just like you did, via the `run` command, but exposing a port publicly.

```
docker run --name postgres -it -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=mannu -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword postgres
```

When it finished initializing and when you finish adding databases and users you can fire up your Django app and it'll connect.

[further reading on postgres env variables](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/postgres#environment-variables)

**Scenario 2 - using composed database**

There's a lot of explaining here, as you have to set up a `entrypoint` that will wait until the DB is fully initialized. But I've already written a step by step answer on how to do it [here on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50248217/error-database-is-uninitialized-and-password-option-is-not-specified/50250205#50250205)

Your situation is basically the same except for the DB service. You leave your compose nearly as it is now, with a little changes:

```
version: '3'

services:
    web:
        image: 1ce04167758d
        command: python manage.py runserver
        volumes:
            - .:/code
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        entrypoint: ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]

    postgres:
        image: postgres
        env_file:
            - .env
```

I've added a `entrypoint` that is supposed to wait until your DB service completes initialization (for instructions on how to set it up you should refer to the link I provided earlier on).

I can see you've defined a entrypoint already - I'd suggest removing this `entrypoint` from `Dockerfile`, move it to the `compose` file and merge it with what I've described in the referred link. It's a common practice in commercial/bigger environments, as you might have many `entrypoint`s, or/and as your `entrypoint` might not be intended to run while building - like the one I suggest is.

I've removed DB port mapping as you shouldn't expose services if there's no need - if only the `web` service is supposed to use the DB, then we shouldn't expose the DB for other possibilities.

With the above configuration, your Django configuration would be perfectly fine.

**edit from comments**

The `0.0.0.0` IP provided for postgres states that the server will listen on all incoming connections. It means that in `settings.py` you should specify **not** the `0.0.0.0` address but a address of the host on which your service runs - in your case I guess it's run on your computer - so simply running:

```
$ ifconfig
```

on your host will give your your local ip address ( `192.x.x.x` or `10.x.x.x` ) and this IP is what you specify in `settings`

Comment: I followed all your procedure, but when I run the Postgres instance, I got the log ```LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432``     but when I used that IP i.e 0.0.0.0 in settings.py, I am getting     ``` 
could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "0.0.0.0" and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?could not connect``` How can I resolve this?

Comment: I've added explanation for your problem at the end of my answer.

Comment: Good to hear, take care ;)

Answer (score 13):

I tried various steps but this is the one which solved my problem.

> docker stop $(docker ps -qa) && docker system prune -af --volumes

> docker-compose up

Comment: thank you so much u just saved my life lol

Comment: Careful, this will erase all images you have locally.